# How to update Store with NgRX Data?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

My component structure

## [image]

In case.component im caching the case data in Case entity of store then i fetch that from child components (case-actions, case-activity... etc).

But when i update remotely the Case from any child component I dont know how to refresh the cached data in parent component (case.component) to replicate that on child components again.

Im trying to do with best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice:

- You shouldnt fetch the data from a child component, the parent should
  fetch the data then pass it to the children using an `@Input()` and
  you should update your store from the parent aswell by using an
  `@Output()` that is triggered by the children. That way, the
  parent(container) have almost all the logic.

Quick fix that I don't recommend:

- If you just want a fix, subscribe to your selector in the children
  and emit the value to the parent using an `@Output()`